# chroot command: failed to run command ‘node’: No such file or directory

Tags: chroot

I run this command at the command line:

```
 $ sudo chroot . node test/simple.js
```

And I get this error:

```
chroot: failed to run command ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

makes sense, since the node executable is located in a file below the PWD. So what is a good way to get the node executable within the PWD, should I symlink it?

**Ultimately however**, I am most interested in allowing all executables to run in the chroot jail, but only allow reading and writing to files within the chroot jail, AKA:

```
randos/
   node
   a.js
jail/
  foo/foo.js
```

so say I do:

```
cd jail/foo
sudo chroot . ../randos/node ../randos/a.js
```

that should fail because I shouldn't be able to read randos/a.js.
**But if I do this**:

```
cd jail/foo
sudo chroot . ../randos/node foo.js
```

then it should work, even if the node executable file is not a file within the jail.

Also, *as an aside*, if anyone knows how to get chroot to run without sudo for a certain directory, that'd be good.

Comment: Unfortunately none of that is how it works. What is your actual goal?

Comment: @MichaelHomer yeah you might be right, here is the actual goal: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24633

Answer (score 1):

I would use the symlink option.

Also to answer your aside, I would edit your sudoers file.

Add a line that looks like:

```
SOMEUSER  ALL=/usr/sbin/chroot /DIR/TO/JAIL
```

Comment: thanks for the info, upvoted. yeah but in this for a library, I need all executables outside the jail to be available, and I'd rather not permanently change the sudoers file.

Comment: Yea, that makes things more interesting... @AlexanderMills

Comment: yeah I don't think chroot works the way I want, might have to find a different solution, perhaps a Docker container is the only way idk

Comment: Here is the ultimate goal, btw: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24633